# How do i refrence my validation method (true or false) when i makeing a conditional statment?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

so i have an ArryList called "files"
and ive created a validation method for validating
if its when used you are callling on a valid index refrence:

```
// validation method of an ArrayList called "files"
public boolean validIndex(int index){
    if(index >= 0 && index < files.size()){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

The insted of just calling on the get method
i want to be able to refrence "validIndex" method when calling an on an item from the arrayList.

```
// Trying to make this one work:
Public void listFile(int index){
    if(validindex(index) = true){
        file.get(index);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Index: " + index + "is not valid!");
    }
}
```

please help

Comment: Write it as `if(validindex(index))`

Comment: `if (a) {return true;} else {return false;}` is the same thing as `return a;`. If you want to put it to a variable, `boolean ex = a`. As for your second method, sometimes it's easier to program for the bad conditions first: `if (!validIndex) { sout("Bad index!"); return; }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code in a more concise way:

```
// validation method of an ArrayList called "files"
public boolean validIndex(int index){
    return (index >= 0) && (index < files.size());
}
```

because

```
if (bool) return true;
else return false;
```

is the same thing as `return bool;`
For the other function, simply use:

```
// Trying to make this one work:
public void listFile(int index){ // Public should be public
    if(validIndex(index)){ // No need for = true (which should be == true
// even if you use it) and validindex(index) should be
// validIndex(index) because that is the correct name of your function
        file.get(index);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Index: " + index + "is not valid!");
    }
}
```

You can also look at some boolean logic to get more familiar with `if` statements and other things.

Hopefully my explanations and code comments were helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you are using `=` instead of `==`on `if(validindex(index) = true)`.

With `=` you are setting the value of `validIndex(index)` to `true`. And that does nothing.

What you are trying to do is compare, that is done with `==`. However, comparing a boolean is pointless since the bool already is `true` or `false`. You simply can use `if(validindex(index))`.

The same can be said about the `validIndex` function. You have the following structure:

```
if ($YourLogic){
  //logic is true
  return true;
}
else{
  //logic is false
  return false;
}
```

As you can see, you are returning the same value your logic is. You can simply return it directly like this:

```
public boolean validIndex(int index){
  return index >= 0 && index < files.size();
}
```